Deploy a Java library to Maven Central: Deploy fails because of gpg
7 years ago, I created a Java library ( com.florianingerl.util.regex ) and put it on Maven central.
Someone told me a bug and I fixed it, but I can't deploy any more because of the following error:
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.15/plexus-utils-3.0.15.jar (239 kB at 1.1 MB/s)
gpg: keybox '/home/imelf/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: skipped "6919F5E8": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.748 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-05-22T17:16:56+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) on project regex: Exit code: 2 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

My pom.xml looks like this:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.florianingerl.util</groupId>
    <artifactId>regex</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.10</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <name>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>This is a Regular Expressions library for Java. Compared to java.util.regex, it supports Recursive and Conditional Regular Expressions, Capture Trees and Plugins.</description>
    <url>https://github.com/florianingerl/com.florianingerl.util.regex</url>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>GNU General Public License, version 2</name>
            <url>https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/florianingerl/com.florianingerl.util.regex.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://github.com/florianingerl/com.florianingerl.util.regex.git</developerConnection>
        <url>http://github.com/florianingerl/com.florianingerl.util.regex/tree/master</url>
    </scm>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Florian Ingerl</name>
            <email>imelflorianingerl@gmail.com</email>
            <organization>Florian Ingerl</organization>
            <organizationUrl>https://github.com/florianingerl</organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <gpg.keyname>6919F5E8</gpg.keyname>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.9</source>
                    <target>1.9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <keyname>${gpg.keyname}</keyname>
                            <passphraseServerId>${gpg.keyname}</passphraseServerId>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                    <autoReleaseAfterClose>false</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>



    </build>



</project>

Unfortunately, I don't know any more what this stuff with gpg is all about and where my secret key is and where I have to put it.
However, and can still log in to https://oss.sonatype.org/ and see my library there. I remember that I had to do something there 7 years ago to make the library available on MavenCentral.
I can also open a Kleopatra-GPG-Gui and it shows me a key, that I probably used 7 years ago. It is
Name: Florian Ingerl (Hobby Java Developer )
Email: ...
Gültig bis: 15.2.2029
Schlüssel-Kennung:
and I have gpg installed, which I can verify if I type
gpg --version

into the terminal
What are the steps I need to take to be able to deploy a new version of my library with the bugs fixed?

Have you read the documentation on oss?

I am just reading. Can you provide me with the link to the documentation I should read ?

https://central.sonatype.org/publish/publish-guide/

Using ancient old plugins... please upgrade to most recent version https://maven.apache.org/plugins/
